# Combine Mono with every Flux element emitted

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a Flux and Mono as below:

```
Mono<MyRequest> req = request.bodyToMono(MyRequest.class);
Mono<List<String>> mono1 = req.map(r -> r.getList());;
Flux<Long> flux1 = req.map(r -> r.getVals()) // getVals() return list of Long
        .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
```

Now for each number in `flux1`, I want to call a method where params are the id from `flux1` and the `List<String>` from `mono1`. Something like,

```
flux1.flatMap(id -> process(id, mono1))
```

But passing and processing same `mono1` results in error `Only one connection receive subscriber allowed`. How can I achieve above? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both information are coming from the same source, you could just run the whole thing with one pipeline like this and wrap both elements in a `Tuple` or better, a domain object that has more meaning:

```
Mono<MyRequest> req = // ...
Flux<Tuple2<Long, List<String>>> tuples = req.flatMapMany(r ->
        Flux.fromIterable(r.getVals())
                .map(id -> Tuples.of(id, r.getList()))
);
// once there, you can map that with your process method like
tuples.map(tup -> process(tup.getT1(), tup.getT2());
```

Note that this looks unusual, and this basically comes from the structure of that object you're receiving.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @brian-clozel. I ended up doing `req
  .flatMap(r -> Flux.fromIterable(r.getVals())
   .flatMap(id -> process(id, r.getList()))`your answer looks good too.